# how to get id of BorderContainer at runtime in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, mxml

I am getting error while attempting to get id of BorderContainer at runtime. I tried using getStyle but it is also failing.

```
    <s:Panel id="colorPanel" 
         title="Dem display color"
         width="500" height="500">
    <s:layout>
        <s:BasicLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Label id="label" y="4" horizontalCenter="0"/>
    <s:BorderContainer id="Box1" x="70" y="70" height="50" width="50" backgroundColor="#0000ff">

    </s:BorderContainer>
    <s:BorderContainer id="Box2" x="90" y="90" height="51" width="50" backgroundColor="#00ff00">

    </s:BorderContainer>
    <s:BorderContainer id="Box3" x="50" y="50" height="52" width="50" backgroundColor="#ff0000">

    </s:BorderContainer>

    <s:Button label="Click" click="
              colorPanel.setElementIndex(colorPanel.getElementAt(0),3);
              label.text = ""+colorPanel.getElementAt(0).id ;
              ">

    </s:Button>
</s:Panel>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need that, but you can use the `name` instead of the `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of casting to **BorderContainer**, it is safe to cast to **UIComponent**. In your example it crashes when the returned element is **Label** instead of **BorderContainer**. You can do as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    ]]></fx:Script>
<s:Panel id="colorPanel"
         title="Dem display color"
         width="500" height="500">
    <s:layout>
        <s:BasicLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Label id="label" text="Red" y="4" horizontalCenter="0"/>
    <s:BorderContainer id="Blue" x="70" y="70" height="50" width="50" backgroundColor="#0000ff">

    </s:BorderContainer>
    <s:BorderContainer id="Green" x="90" y="90" height="51" width="50" backgroundColor="#00ff00">

    </s:BorderContainer>
    <s:BorderContainer id="Red" x="50" y="50" height="52" width="50" backgroundColor="#ff0000">

    </s:BorderContainer>

    <s:Button label="Click" click="{
          colorPanel.setElementIndex(colorPanel.getElementAt(1),3);
          label.text = UIComponent(colorPanel.getElementAt(3)).id;}"/>
</s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found seems like over rigidness on the part of Adobe. I was able to get value of Id the moment I casted the returned Element as BorderContainer. So we have to live with it till Adobe lowers it's compiler's expectations from us.

```
label.text = ""+ BorderContainer(colorPanel.getElementAt(0)).id ;
```